# how to ignore lf,crlf difference in beyond compare folder compare?

Tags: beyondcompare

I have 2 same php file. one is download in win7, another is from linux.
I use folder compare function in beyond compare.
Beyond compare regards them as different file because one is PC, another one is UNIX.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y9B5.jpg):
[image: screenshot]

I would like to ignore this difference ,how to do ?

Answer (score 4):

Can you check the session settings (In the menu under Settings -> Session Settings) if you compare also the line endings?

[image]
You find the flag on the botton of the options.

---

If you need a pre-check in folder compare you can use the following settings:

[image]
(See the different filesize 18 to 19 Byte - The difference is the LF)

You need the overwrite quick test results. Without this the other checks return already a result. With this, your comparison will need more time.

Comment: is that only for text compare? how to do it in folder compare?

Comment: See my update for binary comparison in folder compare.

Comment: Binary comparison will not ignore lf,crlf difference when I do folder compare

Comment: I revised the question,how to ignore lf,crlf difference in beyond compare folder compare?

Comment: No, I made my first correction under time pressure and without attention. I hope I have it now.

Comment: @knut on BeyondCompare 4, more specifically on session settings, I do not see that "Importance" tab, even though it should appear ([as it shows here](https://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?sessiontext.html)).

Comment: @GonçaloPeres Are you in the settings for the file compare? In Folder compare the flag is missing. You see it in the title of "Session Settings - <here>"

Comment: @knut no, and that was the reason. I was in Folder Compare. Just tested with file compare and was able to see the "Importance" tab.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the ANSI format between PC and UNIX I simply selected the Rules-based comparison from the Folder Compare - Session Settings window (Session>Session Settings>Comparison). Note the version of beyond compare I am using is Version 3.3.7 (build 15876):

[image: Folder Compare - Session Settings window]